# Link to Authors blog posts

Tags: users, author, blog

I am trying to create a link in my template that allows the user to see there own blog posts the code that i am using is `<li><a href="?author=<?php the_author_ID(); ?>">test</a></li>` but it is only taking me to `?author=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_author_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_ID) says in Codex:

> It displays the unique numeric user ID for **the author of a post**; the ID is assigned by WordPress when a user account is created. This tag must be used **within The Loop**.

So, it won't work.

Try using the following code* within a loop:

```
<li class="author vcard">
   <a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'my-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
</li>
```

<sup>* *Thanks to [Ian Stewart](http://themeshaper.com/author/superuser/)*</sup>

Comment: I want it so in the main menu there is a link saying blog and it links to the users post

Comment: Have you tried the solution with an [`author.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)?